# Looping through a mysql join

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a drop down menu with subcategories.

Here is my MYSQL code

```
SELECT root.categoryName AS root_name, root.id AS root_id, down1.categoryName AS down1_name,
down1.id AS down1_id, down2.categoryName AS down2_name, down2.equipmentID AS down2_id
FROM category AS root
LEFT OUTER 
JOIN category AS down1 ON down1.parent_id = root.id
LEFT OUTER 
JOIN category AS down2 ON down2.parent_id = down1.id
```

What I a getting is

```
Category 1 28 Sub Category 1 63 NULL NULL
Category 1 28 Sub Category 2 61 NULL NULL
Category 1 28 Sub Category 3 62 NULL NULL

Category 2 29 Sub Category 4 71 NULL NULL
Category 2 29 Sub Category 5 70 NULL NULL

Category 3 27 Sub Category 6 30 Product 1 33
Category 3 27 Sub Category 6 30 Product 2 54
```

What I am wanting is:

```
-Category 1 (id)
    -Sub Category 1 (id)
    -Sub Category 2 (id)
    -Sub Category 3 (id)

-Category 2 (id)
    -Sub Category 4 (id)
    -Sub Category 5 (id)
    -Sub Category 6 (id)

-Category 3 (id)
    -Sub Category 7 (id)
        -Product 1 (id)
        -Product 2 (id)
    -Sub Category 2 (id)
    -Sub Category 3 (id)
```

Comment: OK. So what have you done to try to get the categories displayed the way you want?

Comment: Don't confuse data retrieval with data display!

Comment: i dont think you can get hierarchical results in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can't get multidimensional data in one query. You can either:

1. Write one query that gets you all the data, then process it to build the proper structure. Looks like that's what you started doing. You could process your data after the query to structure the way you want.
2. Make several queries. One for the first level of data (categories), then one for each subcategory. This is easier to write but not efficient because you end up making a lot of SQL queries.